# Дана прямоугольная матрица. Отсортировать каждый столбец с четным номером по возрастанию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код ниже должен выводить матрицу n с четными столбцами:

```
import random

x = random.randint(2,7)
y = x + random.randint(2,5)
a = [[random.randint(-10 , 10) for i in range(y)] for j in range(x)]


n = []

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print("{:4d}".format(j), end=' ')
    print()

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        n.append(i[::2])


print(n)
```

Код не работает, мне нужно чтобы он выводил четные столбцы матрицы, а он выводит лишь одну строку с четными по индексу элементами

Answer (score 0):

Замените второй цикл в вашем коде на этот:

```python
for i in a:
    n.append(i[1::2])
```

Для нечетных столбцов срез будет такой `i[::2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint


def print_matrix(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print(''.join(['{:>4d}'.format(col) for col in row]))
    print()


rows = randint(2,7)
cols = rows + randint(2,5)
matrix = [[randint(-10 , 10) for __ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]

print_matrix(matrix)

for col_even_index in range(1, cols, 2):
    for row_new_index, value in enumerate(sorted([matrix[row_old_index][col_even_index] for row_old_index in range(rows)])):
        matrix[row_new_index][col_even_index] = value

print_matrix(matrix)


  10   1  -6   0   1   3  -2  -3   1  -9  -5
   6   2   5   2   2  -9  -1   5  -4  -5   7
  -7   6  -5  -7   6 -10   0  -8  -9  10  -8
   3  -9  -7   8   3  -9   1   4  -8   0   2
  -1  -7   9 -10  -7   0  10 -10   5   4  -4
   4  -8  -6  -8  -6  -9  -9  -7   6   4   9

  10  -9  -6 -10   1 -10  -2 -10   1  -9  -5
   6  -8   5  -8   2  -9  -1  -8  -4  -5   7
  -7  -7  -5  -7   6  -9   0  -7  -9   0  -8
   3   1  -7   0   3  -9   1  -3  -8   4   2
  -1   2   9   2  -7   0  10   4   5   4  -4
   4   6  -6   8  -6   3  -9   5   6  10   9
```